# DataGrid Rows Empty

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Newbie here, but lost in DataGrid (WPF) and ItemSource List...

public MainWindow()
        {

```
        InitializeComponent();
        string item = null;

        List<Car> auta = new List<Car>();    

        //string Maker, string typer, string body_typer, string colorr, int year_of_maker, int kwr, string equip_levelr, decimal pricer, string extrasr
        auta.Add(new Car("Skoda", "Octavia", "Sedan", "White", "1999", " 110", "Classic", " 1999", "Defend-Lock"));
        //auticka.Add(new Car("Skoda", "Octavia", "Sedan", "White", 1999, 110, "Classic", 1999, "Defend-Lock"));



         GridNamedats.ItemsSource = auta;
```

Now DataGrid XAML:

```
{
 <DataGrid x:Name=" GridNamedats" Margin="0,71,0,0" SelectionChanged="DataGrid_SelectionChanged" ColumnWidth="SizeToHeader" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Make" Width="70"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Type" Width="70" Foreground="#FFBBBBBB"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Body Type" Width="70"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Color" Width="70" Foreground="#FFBBBBBB"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Year of Make"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="[KW]" Foreground="#FFBBBBBB"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Equip Level" Width="100"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Price [€]" Width="70" Foreground="#FFBBBBBB"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Extras" Width="160"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Foreground="#FFBBBBBB"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

}
```

The issue is that DataGrid has empty cells in row. In class Car there is of course Constructor, a getters+Setters

Thank You Very Much for your Advice !
Oblud

Comment: It has empty cells ? Means does that one row appear in that datagrid or all the cells are empty ?

Comment: Hi, row does  appear, but with no values

Comment: please provide your car class

Answer (score 0):

Try putting properties names in your `Binding` attibute of your `DataGrid`.

Replace this :

```
Binding="{x:Null}"
```

with this :

```
Binding="{Binding Name}"
```

You can put up your property names in the above statement. The `Name` property is for example purpose only.

Comment: I have tried Binding="{Binding Make}", because of "Make" is in Class Car as public string Make {get;set;}, but with no  result (empty cell)